# What is the best way to prefault in the stack for a pthreads thread?

Tags: linux, memory-management, stack, pthreads, real-time

I am writing code for a real-time program running in an embedded Linux system. As it is critical that we don't stall unpredictably on page faults, I would like to prefault in the stack so that the region that we use is guaranteed to be covered by a `mlockall()` call.

For the main thread this is simple enough; simply do a few big `alloca()`s and make sure to do a write every few pages. This works because at program startup, the stack limit is much larger than the amount we need; we end up allocating exactly how much we prefault in.

However, for pthread stacks, will they be allocated using `MAP_GROWSDOWN` as well? If so, what's the best way to prefault them in, considering that:

1. We don't know how much of the (known) stack size is consumed by libc startup
2. We don't want to allocate more memory to the stack than is necessary

I'm aware that I can use `pthread_attr_setstack` to pass in a manually-allocated stack, but this complicates cleaning up after the thread, and so I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

As such, what's the best way to perform this prefaulting? It would be sufficient if there was an easy way to find out the lower bound of the stack (just above the guard page); at this point I could simply write to every page from there to the current stack pointer.

Note that portability is not a concern; we'd be happy to have a solution that works only under x86-32 and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `pthread_attr_setstacksize` you can still have automatic allocation with a known size.

glibc nptl leaves guard pages between the stacks, so you could also set a `SEGV` handler and simply scribble until you fault and then `longjmp` out of the loop.  That'd be ugly!

Edit:  A really nonportable way would be to open `/proc/self/maps` to find your stacks!

Comment: Is there a guarantee in the API contract that `pthread_attr_setstacksize` will not use things similar to `GROWSDOWN`, ie, that `mlockall()` will immediately apply to the entire stack at time of allocation without additional prefaulting?

Comment: Thread stacks are all bounded in glibc nptl.  I don't know offhand if that's part of the spec, but I suspect it is.  A quick look shows that nptl also uses a stack pool, so if you're creating/destroying threads your code should not fail if you get a "warm" stack.

Comment: all right, I guess that's good enough for us for now - hopefully we won't get into the situation where pageins block anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

yes. if you have called mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE) before pthread_create, page fault for thread stack will happen when starting the thread. and after that, there will be no page fault again while accessing stack in the thread.
so people always set the suitable thread size for the new created thread to avoid lock too much memory for the future coming threads.
take a look at:
https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Threaded_RT-application_with_memory_locking_and_stack_handling_example

if you change the thread stack size to 7MB, you will see:
Initial count                 : Pagefaults, Major:0 (Allowed >=0), Minor:190 (Allowed >=0)
mlockall() generated          : Pagefaults, Major:0 (Allowed >=0), Minor:393 (Allowed >=0)
malloc() and touch generated  : Pagefaults, Major:0 (Allowed >=0), Minor:25633 (Allowed >=0)
2nd malloc() and use generated: Pagefaults, Major:0 (Allowed 0), Minor:0 (Allowed 0)

Look at the output of ps -leyf, and see that the RSS is now about 100 [MB]
Press  to exit
I am an RT-thread with a stack that does not generate page-faults during use, stacksize=7340032
Caused by creating thread     : Pagefaults, Major:0 (Allowed >=0), Minor:1797 (Allowed >=0)
Caused by using thread stack  : Pagefaults, Major:0 (Allowed 0), Minor:0 (Allowed 0)

1797 page faults happen while creating thread, it is about 7MB.
-barry